# (U) Ruby Extensions: rb_gc_mark() and instance variables

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension, mark-and-sweep

I'm writing a ruby extension that defines a class.
If I use `Data_Wrap_Struct()` to implement my callback for `rb_define_alloc_func()`, do I need to manually mark and free the instance variables?  Or is that still handled for me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby's GC will collect any Ruby objects that are referenced in your Ruby object's instance variables. You don't have to, and should not, free Ruby instance variables yourself (i.e. any objects accessed with `rb_iv_set()` / `rb_iv_get()` in your extension).

However, if the wrapped *C struct* references Ruby objects, then you'll have to mark those in the `mark` callback you are passing to `Data_Wrap_Struct()`.

(And you will always have to free the underlying struct, and do any other clean-up that may be necessary such as closing files, sockets, etc. in your `free` callback.)